# React Three Fiber ShaderMaterial animation problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I've been trying to find where I made a mistake maybe 30 times, but I couldn't find it. There is no problem in the view, but the animation does not work in the  Component.
The view works well, but the animation needs to work in the code I wrote in the fragment. The link I referenced is

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3krH52AhPqk.

```
import React, { Suspense, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Canvas, useFrame,extend } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import fragmentShader from "./shader/fragment.js";
import vertexShader from "./shader/vertex.js";
import fragment1 from "./shader/shaderSun/fragment.js";
import vertex1 from "./shader/shaderSun/vertex.js";



// function Perlin(props) {
//   return (
//     <mesh {...props}>
//       <sphereBufferGeometry />
//       <meshPhysicalMaterial />
//       <shaderMaterial
//         attach="material"
//         args={[
//           {
//             uniforms: [1.1, 30, 30],
//             vertexShader: vertex1,
//             fragmentShader: fragment1,
//           },
//         ]}
//         side={THREE.DoubleSide}
//       />
//     </mesh>
//   );
// }
class CustomMaterial extends THREE.ShaderMaterial {
  constructor() {
    super({
      uniforms: { time:{value:0},resolution:{value:new THREE.Vector4()} },
      vertexShader: vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
    
  }

}

extend({ CustomMaterial })
function Sphere(props) {
  //   const data = useMemo(() => ({ fragment }));
  const myMesh = React.useRef();
  // useFrame(({ clock }) => {
  //   myMesh.current.rotation.z += 0.1;
  // });

  // const data = useMemo(
  //   () => ({
  //     uniforms: {},
  //     fragmentShader,
  //     vertexShader,
  //     uPerlin: { value: null },
  //   }),
  //   []
  // );
  return (
    <mesh {...props} ref={myMesh}>
      <sphereBufferGeometry args={[1, 30, 30]} />
      {/* 
      <Perlin /> */}
<customMaterial attach="material"  />
    </mesh>
  );
}
function index() {
 

  return (
    <Canvas >
      {" "}
      {/* <spotLight
        intensity={0.5}
        angle={0.2}
        penumbra={1}
        position={[5, -25, 10]}
      />{" "} */}
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Sphere />
        {/* <Perlin /> */}
      </Suspense>
      <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default index;
```

**fragmentShader**

```
const fragment = `
//
// Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex
//               noise functions.
//      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.
//  Maintainer : ijm
//     Lastmod : 20110822 (ijm)
//     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.
//               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.
//               https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise
//
uniform float time;
uniform float progress;
uniform sampler2D texture1; 
uniform vec4 resolution;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
float PI= 3.141592653589793238;
vec4 mod289(vec4 x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
    }
    
    float mod289(float x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
    }
    
    vec4 permute(vec4 x) {
    return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
    }
    
    float permute(float x) {
    return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
    }
    
    vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
    {
    return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
    }
    
    float taylorInvSqrt(float r)
    {
    return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
    }
    
    vec4 grad4(float j, vec4 ip)
    {
    const vec4 ones = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p,s;
    
    p.xyz = floor( fract (vec3(j) * ip.xyz) * 7.0) * ip.z - 1.0;
    p.w = 1.5 - dot(abs(p.xyz), ones.xyz);
    s = vec4(lessThan(p, vec4(0.0)));
    p.xyz = p.xyz + (s.xyz*2.0 - 1.0) * s.www;
    
    return p;
    }
    
    // (sqrt(5) - 1)/4 = F4, used once below
    #define F4 0.309016994374947451
    
    float snoise(vec4 v)
    {
    const vec4  C = vec4( 0.138196601125011,  // (5 - sqrt(5))/20  G4
    0.276393202250021,  // 2 * G4
    0.414589803375032,  // 3 * G4
    -0.447213595499958); // -1 + 4 * G4
    
    // First corner
    vec4 i  = floor(v + dot(v, vec4(F4)) );
    vec4 x0 = v -   i + dot(i, C.xxxx);
    
    // Other corners
    
    // Rank sorting originally contributed by Bill Licea-Kane, AMD (formerly ATI)
    vec4 i0;
    vec3 isX = step( x0.yzw, x0.xxx );
    vec3 isYZ = step( x0.zww, x0.yyz );
    //  i0.x = dot( isX, vec3( 1.0 ) );
    i0.x = isX.x + isX.y + isX.z;
    i0.yzw = 1.0 - isX;
    //  i0.y += dot( isYZ.xy, vec2( 1.0 ) );
    i0.y += isYZ.x + isYZ.y;
    i0.zw += 1.0 - isYZ.xy;
    i0.z += isYZ.z;
    i0.w += 1.0 - isYZ.z;
    
    // i0 now contains the unique values 0,1,2,3 in each channel
    vec4 i3 = clamp( i0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec4 i2 = clamp( i0-1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec4 i1 = clamp( i0-2.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    
    //  x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxxx
    //  x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxxx
    //  x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxxx
    //  x3 = x0 - i3  + 3.0 * C.xxxx
    //  x4 = x0 - 1.0 + 4.0 * C.xxxx
    vec4 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxxx;
    vec4 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyyy;
    vec4 x3 = x0 - i3 + C.zzzz;
    vec4 x4 = x0 + C.wwww;
    
    // Permutations
    i = mod289(i);
    float j0 = permute( permute( permute( permute(i.w) + i.z) + i.y) + i.x);
    vec4 j1 = permute( permute( permute( permute (
    i.w + vec4(i1.w, i2.w, i3.w, 1.0 ))
    + i.z + vec4(i1.z, i2.z, i3.z, 1.0 ))
    + i.y + vec4(i1.y, i2.y, i3.y, 1.0 ))
    + i.x + vec4(i1.x, i2.x, i3.x, 1.0 ));
    
    // Gradients: 7x7x6 points over a cube, mapped onto a 4-cross polytope
    // 7*7*6 = 294, which is close to the ring size 17*17 = 289.
    vec4 ip = vec4(1.0/294.0, 1.0/49.0, 1.0/7.0, 0.0) ;
    
    vec4 p0 = grad4(j0,   ip);
    vec4 p1 = grad4(j1.x, ip);
    vec4 p2 = grad4(j1.y, ip);
    vec4 p3 = grad4(j1.z, ip);
    vec4 p4 = grad4(j1.w, ip);
    
    // Normalise gradients
    vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
    p0 *= norm.x;
    p1 *= norm.y;
    p2 *= norm.z;
    p3 *= norm.w;
    p4 *= taylorInvSqrt(dot(p4,p4));
    
    // Mix contributions from the five corners
    vec3 m0 = max(0.6 - vec3(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2)), 0.0);
    vec2 m1 = max(0.6 - vec2(dot(x3,x3), dot(x4,x4)            ), 0.0);
    m0 = m0 * m0;
    m1 = m1 * m1;
    return 49.0 * ( dot(m0*m0, vec3( dot( p0, x0 ), dot( p1, x1 ), dot( p2, x2 )))
    + dot(m1*m1, vec2( dot( p3, x3 ), dot( p4, x4 ) ) ) ) ;
    
    }
void main(){ 
// vec4 p=vec4(vPosition*5.,time*0.2);
// float noisy=fbm(p);
// vec4 p1=vec4(vPosition*2.,time*0.02);
// float spots=max(snoise(p1),0.);

// gl_FragColor=vec4(noisy);
// gl_FragColor*=mix(1.,spots,0.7);
// // gl_FragColor = vec4(vUv,0.0,1.);
// // gl_FragColor=vec4(vPosition,1.);
float noisy=snoise(vec4(vPosition*5.,time));
gl_FragColor=vec4(vUv,0.0,1.);
gl_FragColor=vec4(noisy);
// gl_FragColor=vec4(vPosition,1.);


}
`;
export default fragment;
```

**Vertex**

```
const vertex = `
uniform float time;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec2 pixels;
float PI = 3.141592653589793238;
void main(){
    vUv = uv;
    vPosition = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(position,1.0);
}

`;
export default vertex;
```

Thank you in advance for your opinions.